# Anyone know how to fix hadoop-functions.sh "syntax error near unexpected token `<'"?

Tags: hadoop

I've configured Hadoop 3.1.1 on my MacPro running OSX 10.14.2, and I'm getting the following error when I run start-all.sh

```sh
$ sudo /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/sbin/start-all.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
```

Same issues starting the datanodes, secondary namenodes, resourcemanager, and nodemanagers.

I have found a similar bug reference online:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-12571.

**Update**
After some debugging, the root cause is bash "< <(command)" syntax not being accepted for some reason.  The bash versions on the system (/bin/bash and /usr/local/bin/bash from Homebrew) both work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should modify `HDFS_NAMENODE_USER`、`HDFS_DATANODE_USER` and so on in hadoop-env.sh to **current user** instead of **root**! Then before run the `sudo ./start-all.sh` command, you may need to recreate hdfs namenode with `hdfs namenode -format`.